# Mathematical induction used on Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I have no clue how to go about doing this question using induction. It states that the Fibonacci sequence is defined as:

**F<sub>0</sub> = 0** 
**F<sub>1</sub> = 1**  
**F<sub>n</sub> = F<sub>n-2</sub> + F<sub>n-1</sub>** for  **n>=2**

Let **S(n) = F<sub>o</sub> + F<sub>1</sub> + F<sub>2</sub> +...+ F<sub>n</sub>.** Prove that **S(n)= F<sub>n+2</sub> -1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us prove that 
$$S(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}F_i=F_{n+2}-1$$
for all non-negative integers $n$ by induction.

For $n=0$, it holds trivially since $F_2=1$.

Assume that it holds for $n=k$, i.e.
$$S(k)=\sum_{i=0}^{k}F_i=F_{k+2}-1.$$
Then, we have
$$\begin{align}S(k+1)&=\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}F_i\\&=F_{k+1}+\sum_{i=0}^{k}F_k\\&=F_{k+1}+F_{k+2}-1\\&=F_{k+3}-1\\&=F_{(k+1)+2}-1.\end{align}$$

Hence, it holds for $n=k+1$.

Hence, $S(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}F_i=F_{n+2}-1$ for all non-negative integers $n$. **Q.E.D.**

Answer (score 1):

Inductive step:

If $S(n)=F_0 + F_1 + \cdots + F_n=F_{n+2}-1$ then $S(n+1)=S(n)+F_{n+1}=F_{n+2} + F_{n+1} -1= F_{n+3}-1$